# Why did Rama slay a deer after killing Mareecha?

Tags: ramayana, rama

In the last shloka in the Mareecha chapter it is revealed that Rama kills another deer. What is the reason behind this?

> निहत्य पृषतम् च अन्यम् मांसम् आदाय राघवः |
> त्वरमाणो जनस्थानम् ससार अभिमुखः तदा || ३-४४-२७

> Raghava then on killing another spotted deer and on taking its flesh, he hurried himself towards Janasthaana. [3-44-27]

Comment: I would appreciate it if the downvoter can leave a feedback as to how my question can be better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is given by Valmiki a few Sargas later. In Sarga 46, Sita tells Ravana (who has come in the disguise of a Sanyasi, with a design to cunningly abduct Sita):

> samaashvasa muhuurtam tu shakyam vastum iha tvayaa || 3-47-22

> aagamiSyati me bhartaa vanyam aadaaya puSkalam |
> ruruun godhaan varaahaan ca hatvaa aadaaya amiSaan bahu || 3-47-23

**Meaning**: Be comfortable for a bit of time, here it is fit for you to stay (temporarily), and my husband will be coming soon, bringing enough forest produce, and on killing **stags**, mongooses, wild boars he fetches sufficient meat.

i.e. they lived on meat and on whatever produce they could gather in the forest. Even in the Sarga whose last shloka you quoted (sarga 42), Sita wasn't concerned about the life of the deer, i.e. she was not enamored by the beautiful life sprinting there in the form of that deer. Instead, she expressed clearly that if that stag doesn't come "into capture" of Rama willingly, then he should kill it so that she can happily enjoy sitting on that deer skin or decorate her palace walls back in Ayodhya with its skin & antlers. i.e. It is the mesmerizing skin & anlters of that deer, which Sita was after.

And whoever will start about vegetarian Rama & Sita, please learn Sanskrit langiage with grammer first. Then read Valmiki Ramayanam ON YOUR OWN.

Comment: Explain this                                            
     Sarga 36, verse 41 ,Sundar Kand, Valmiki Ramayan 

 No Raghuvanshi eats meat or consumes alcohol; Then why would Lord Rama consume these things? He always fast for four times and on the fifth time eats wild fruits ,roots etc. prescribed in the scriptures...

Comment: There is no statement in any scripture that "...No Raghuvanshi eats meat or consumes alcohol..". Lol and verse 41 in 36th sarga Sunara Kanda of Valmiki Ramayan proves that Rama ate meat, do you realize that? Seetha asks Hanuman how is Raama doing, to which Hanuman replies that since Seetha disappeared Raama is not happy (verse 37) and that he spends his time in sorrow (verse 43 and 44) and narrates activies which Raama is doing in that unhappy and sorrow ful state - not eating meat and not drinking liquor. This is why you should listen to pravachans instead of merely reading.

Answer (score 0):

The flesh was collected by rAma for **havir yajnas i.e.** **offerings to** **devas and pitrus** inline with [*anushasana parva CXVI*](https://sacred-texts.com/hin/m13/m13b081.htm) :

> *One does not, however, incur any fault by eating flesh **sanctified according to the ordinances of the Vedas**.*
>
> *They who **eat flesh in any** **other way** are said to **follow the Rakshasa practice**.*
>
> *The man of cleansed soul should do only such acts as have compassion for their soul. That **flesh which is dedicated in sacrifices
> performed in honour of the deities and the Pitris** is called
> **Havi***